# On the Fredholm Alternative for PDE's in Evan's book

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, compact-operators, linear-pde

I have been studying Fredholm Alternative for PDE's in the book Evans - Partial Differential Equations. The result is:

Theorem 4 (page 321) Precisely  one of the following statements holds:

either

$(\alpha)$ For each $f \in L^2(U)$ there exists a unique weak solution $u$ of
$$
(P_1) \quad \begin{cases}
Lu = f, U \\
u = 0, \partial U
\end{cases}
$$
or else

$(\beta)$ there exists a weak solution $u \neq 0$ of
$$
(P_2) \quad 
\begin{cases}
Lu = 0, U \\
u = 0, \partial U
\end{cases}
$$

I want to understand this Evans's proof. Let me write some steps until I get into my doubt.

It is known that there exists a $\gamma \geq 0$ such that the problem
$$
(P_\gamma) \quad 
\begin{cases}
L_\gamma := Lu + \gamma u = f , U\\
u = 0, \partial U
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique solution for each $f \in L^2(U)$. So, we can define the solution operator
$$S_\gamma : L^{2}(U) \rightarrow H^1_0(U)$$ such that
$$
B_\gamma(S_\gamma(f), \varphi) = \int_U f \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1_0(U),
$$
where $B_\gamma$ is the bilinear form associated to the problem $(P_\gamma)$ which Dirichlet condition. Also consider $i : H^1_0(U) \rightarrow L^2(U)$ the usual compact immersion and define $\overline{S_\gamma} = i \circ S_\gamma$. This operator is continous and compact. I know that, given $f \in L^2(U)$, $u \in H^1_0(U)$ is a weak solution of $(P_1)$ if and only if
$$
u - \gamma \overline{S_\gamma} u = S_\gamma(f).
$$
Also, $u \in H^1_0(U)$ is a weak solution of $(P_2)$ if and only if
$$
u - \gamma \overline{S_\gamma} u = 0.
$$
We can apply Fredholm Alternative to $\gamma \overline{S_\gamma}$ in order to obtain:

Proposition: One of the following statements holds:

either

$(1) \quad$ For all $g \in L^2(U)$ the equation $u - \gamma \overline{S_\gamma} u = g$ has a unique solution

or else

$(2) \quad$ The equation $u - \gamma \overline{S_\gamma} u = 0$ has non trivial solution.

**My doubt:** I could not realize if Evans used the above Proposition to obtain Theorem 4. If he used, how to obtain the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your notations, as you indeed remarked $K := \gamma \overline{S_\gamma}$ is a compact operator on $H := L^2(U)$. Hence, you are trying to solve an equation of the form
$$
(\mathrm{Id} - K) u = g
$$
with $u, g \in H$ and a compact operator $K : H \to H$. Such equations are studied in *Section D.5: Compact operators, Fredholm theory* of *Appendix D: Linear functional analysis* of Evans' book.

The fundamental Fredholm alternative at the abstract level (of which you are trying to prove a consequence for the study of PDEs) precisely corresponds to what you stated as your proposition (see item (iv) of *Theorem 5* in *Appendix D.5* in Evans's book):
$$
\operatorname{kernel} (\mathrm{Id} - K) = \{ 0 \}
\quad
\text{ if and only if }
\quad
\operatorname{range} (\mathrm{Id} - K) = H.
$$
So either the kernel is not reduced to $\{0\}$ and you have a non-zero solution to $u = Ku$, or the range is equal to $H$ and for every $g \in H$ you have a solution to $u - K u = g$ (which is unique since the kernel is $\{ 0\}$).